# CMSIS for Cortex-M1

Tags: arm, embedded, cortex-m, cmsis

Sadly I'm forced to use and obscure microcontroller based on ARM Cortex-M1 core. I just found out that the latest CMSIS (5.2) does not support it and official CMSIS [docs](http://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/Core/html/index.html) say this:

> CMSIS supports the complete range of Cortex-M processors (with
>   exception of Cortex-M1) and the ARMv8-M architecture including
>   security extensions.

I guess Cortex-M1 is not very popular. But what should I do without CMSIS? My vendor ships support package which strangely enough includes CMSIS files for this core, namely, core_cm1.h; it's full of ARM copyrights and does not appear to be written directly by said vendor. File comment lists CMSIS version  V3.20 from 25 February 2013. But I can't find it anywhere else, neither in higher versions of CMSIS nor in lower.

In "Definitive Guide to the ARM Cortex-M0" by Joseph Yiu I found this quote:

> There is also a small chance that the software needs minor adjustment
>   because of execution timing differences. At the time of writing, no
>   CMSIS software package is available for the Cortex-M1. However, you
>   can use the same CMSIS files for the Cortex-M0 on Cortex-M1
>   programming, because they are based on the same version of the ARMv6-M
>   architecture.

I diffed core_cm0.h from CMSIS 4.0 and core_cm1.h from my vendor and found only very minor differences (like, 1 << smthn became 1u << smthn in a couple of places). 
Than I diffed core_cm0.h from CMSIS 5.0.2 and core_cm1.h from my vendor and found *a lot* of differences, structs are different, inline functions for NVIC are different and so on.

So my question is: is it really safe to use core_cm0 for Cortex-M1 even for latest CMSIS? Or should I play it safe and stick to my vendor's files (even though I have no idea where did it get them)?

Comment: Are you really using an "M1 microcontroller" - who makes such a thing?  M1 is a soft-core for FPGA's

Comment: Your vendor has probably just supplied and older version of the M0 CMSIS.  In the CMSIS core not much will have changed for ARMv6-M.  Since it is all provided as source you are equipped to verify that the parts you need are correct for your target.  The only reason there is no Cortex-M1 CMSIS I would guess is because M1 is a soft-core IP for FPGAs and implementations may differ since there are a number of vendor selected options.  I would use the vendor supplied files, as they will presumambly match the silicon options they have selected for the part,

Comment: @Clifford, weell.. it's actually a bit fishy. Vendor does not officially say that this is a Cortex-M1. Officially it's a "high performance RISC core" but as I said in the question, it is shipped with files for M1, I supposed to use armcc and so on. I guess you are right and I should just use vendor supplied files.

Comment: Computing, microcontrollers, have survived for 99% of their history without CMSIS, it is not required, there is a manual from the vendor with addresses.   just use them...You have the source code for all of this right, just look at it.  or better the arm part is minimal to none with respect to cmsis, the rest is your coworkers peripherals that are added on...ask them...

Comment: @old_timer, we are just starting to use this particular chip, so non of my coworkers know anything about it. But reimplementing all the register-defines by hand from manual when _it was already done in cmsis_ is pure madness.

Comment: Have you looked at the CMSIS implementations.  And you are talking about a soft core that you bought to put in an fpga, there are like a handful of registers in the core, the rest are things you implement yourself in the fpga.  as well as any headers.  You question is making no sense.  ARMs text is pretty clear and does make a lot of sense.

Comment: @old_timer sorry, I can't understand what's your point.

Comment: Can you link the datasheet for the part?

Comment: @SeanHoulihane I can but I'm afraid it's in russian since it's actually a russian military mcu. Here's the link http://ic.milandr.ru/upload/iblock/3bb/3bb4bcea6043d85bea314e2fdb1c2f6a.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Cortex-M0 CMSIS-CORE header on Cortex-M1. There are couple of things you need to be aware:
- WFI, WFE and SEV instructions are not available in Cortex-M1.
- Cortex-M1 has an auxiliary control register for I-TCM enable control. You need to declare that manually if you need to switch I-TCM enable.
- CPU ID register has different value
- Instruction execution timings are different
- Interrupt latency is not constant.

There is a lot of code changes from CMSIS-CORE 4 to CMSIS-CORE 5. But those changes are focus on supporting of additional tools, general coding styles and for future extension of CMSIS.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Cortex-M1 is very similar to Cortex-M0 from a software point of view. At the CMSIS level, using core_cm0.h (latest CMSIS) will work fine.

You might also find compiler switches don't support Cortex-M1 - in this case treat it as if it were M0.